# too much specular light opengl

Tags: c, opengl, lighting

these are my settings for diffuse,ambient and specualar and the position of my light. My scene looks extremly lit with specualar light. I have tried adjusting the position of the light but that doesn't to anything. 
    GLfloat greenDiffuseMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0,1.0};
    GLfloat whiteSpecularMaterial[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0};
    GLfloat greenAmbientMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.2,1.0};

```
GLfloat greenEmissiveMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.5,1.0};
GLfloat lightPosition[] = { 0.0,1.0,0.0, 0.0};
GLfloat ambientLight[]  = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat diffuseLight[]  = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat specularLight[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
```

**EDIT 1**

```
 for (int g =0;g<6400;g++){
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        if(mountText %2 ==0){glTexCoord2f(islandVert[g][0] /xscale,islandVert[g][2] / zscale);}
        else{
                glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, greenAmbientMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, greenDiffuseMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, whiteSpecularMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT);
                        glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR);
                    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);}
        glNormal3f(vertNorm[g][0],vertNorm[g][1],vertNorm[g][2]);

        glVertex3f(islandVert[g][0],islandVert[g][1],islandVert[g][2]);
        g++;
        if(mountText %2 ==0){glTexCoord2f(islandVert[g][0] / xscale, islandVert[g][2] / zscale);}
        else{
            glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, whiteSpecularMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, greenAmbientMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, greenDiffuseMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR);
                    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);}
        glNormal3f(vertNorm[g][0],vertNorm[g][1],vertNorm[g][2]);
        glVertex3f(islandVert[g][0],islandVert[g][1],islandVert[g][2]);
        g++;

        if(mountText %2 ==0){glTexCoord2f(islandVert[g][0] / xscale, islandVert[g][2] / zscale);}
        else{
                glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, greenAmbientMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, greenDiffuseMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, whiteSpecularMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR);            
                            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);}
        glNormal3f(vertNorm[g][0],vertNorm[g][1],vertNorm[g][2]);
        glVertex3f(islandVert[g][0],islandVert[g][1],islandVert[g][2]);

        g++;

        if(mountText %2 ==0){glTexCoord2f(islandVert[g][0] / xscale, islandVert[g][2] / zscale);}
        else{
                glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, greenAmbientMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, greenDiffuseMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, whiteSpecularMaterial);
                        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT);
                            glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR);
                    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);}
        glNormal3f(vertNorm[g][0],vertNorm[g][1],vertNorm[g][2]);
        glVertex3f(islandVert[g][0],islandVert[g][1],islandVert[g][2]);
    glEnd();
}
```

Basiclly at each cordinate I check if the texture is on or not and if it's not I want to set it to the original green material. The result I'm getting is that one side of my object is extremly lit up and the other side is ambient. The vertex normals work because there is smooth shading but I think it might have something to do with the position of my light. When I try to change it the scene remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This part alone

```
GLfloat greenEmissiveMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.5,1.0};
```

will already make any object appear in color (0, 1, 0.5) independent of any light source you specify. The real lighting will only *add* to that color, making it even brighter.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do have other materials setGLfloat      greenDiffuseMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0,1.0};
GLfloat whiteSpecularMaterial[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0};
GLfloat greenAmbientMaterial[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.2,1.0};

Comment: Please provide the releevant parts of the code which show the issue you are having, then.